# iteration in product list of several pages with selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping

I need to go through the list of products:

- click on it
- perform some actions on the product page (these actions are simple and already made)
- go back to the list that I was already on
- repeat for all the products of that page

After finishing the product list of this current page, I want to be able to click next and perform the same procedure with the products on the next page.

This is the problem: when it reaches the 10 items of the current page, I have no idea how to change to another page and start all over again.

**Example code html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <title>Produtos</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="srp-actions blue-button"><a class="primary-action-button label" href="">Produto 1</a></div>
<div class="srp-actions blue-button"><a class="primary-action-button label" href="">Produto 2</a></div>
<div class="srp-actions blue-button"><a class="primary-action-button label" href="">Produto 3</a></div>
<div class="srp-actions blue-button"><a class="primary-action-button label" href="">Produto 4</a></div>

    <br/>

<div id="pagination">
        <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="active">1</li>
        <li class="link"><a class="page-link" href="" title="Página 2">2</a></li>
        <li class="link"><a class="page-link" href="" title="Página 2">3</a></li>
        <li class="link"><a class="page-link" href="" title="Página 2">4</a></li>
        <li class="next"><a class="page-link" href="" rel="next" title="Avançar">next</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code Java:**

```
int size = driver.findElements(By.className("page-link")).size();
    System.out.println("Numero de paginas : " + size);
    for(int j = 1 ; j < size ; j++) {                
        if (j < 2) {// we don't need to navigate to the first page
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Avançar >")).click(); // navigate to page number j
        }           

        String pagesearch = driver.getCurrentUrl();


    for(int i=1;i< links.size();i++){

    links= driver.findElements(By.linkText("Produto"));

    WebDriverWait wait3 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait3.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.linkText("Produto")));

    links.get(i).click();

    Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic logic would be:

1. Go to the first product list page.
2. Grab all the product links. Navigate to each product page and do stuff.
3. Go back to the product list page and click Next.

You will repeat 2 & 3 until there is no Next link.

```
String url = "http://www.example.com"; // the first page of the product list page
driver.get(url);
List<WebElement> next;
while (true)
{
    // wait for and get all the product links
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    List<WebElement> productLinks = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.linkText("Produto")));
    // loop through the product links
    for (WebElement productLink : productLinks)
    {
        driver.get(productLink.getAttribute("href")); // navigate to product page
        // do stuff on product page
    }

    // now we're done with all products on this page, go back to the product list page that we were last on
    driver.get(url);

    // look for a Next link
    next = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("li.next"));
    if (next.isEmpty())
    {
        // Next link DOES NOT exist, exit loop
        break;
    }

    // Next link DOES exists, click it to go to the next page
    next.get(0).click();
    // may need to wait for page transition here
    url = driver.getCurrentUrl(); // store the current product list page
```

Comment: Can you please also add a Python version. I am unable to reproduce your for loop in python.

Comment: @JeshKundem This question was specifically about Java so I won't be adding a python version. You should be able to search for loops in python or specifically looping through a collection of web elements for python/selenium and get what you need.