# How to pull text from category list page of products as an Xpath and add it to a list in Selenium Java

Tags: java, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I'm trying to select the name of each product on a category list page like so ( ex : https://www.prana.com/women/clothing/tops.html#page=1 )

I have a for loop going through the Xpath but it keeps returning the error that - "Xpath" is [object Text] it should be an element. Which is correct. My question is how do I get the text? I have looked all over but can't seem to find a correct answer- This is what I have now.

```
List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root-wrapper\"]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[3]/ul/li[1]/a/h2/text()")); 
for(int i=0; i <allElements.size(); i++) {
   allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root-wrapper\"]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[3]/ul/li["+i+"]/a/h2/text()")); 
}

System.out.println(Integer.toString(allElements.size()));
   for (WebElement element: allElements) {
      System.out.println((element).getText());
```

So I want it to continue until there are no more of those "elements" (text) and then list them for me.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

I did see something similar with href here : [iteration in product list of several pages with selenium java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38311474/iteration-in-product-list-of-several-pages-with-selenium-java)

Im going to see If I can implement it with

```
driver.findElements(By.className(".product-name *then enter a blank variable here*" );
```

Answer (score 0):

`text()` in XPath is use to match TextNode. Besides TextNode, there are ElementNode and AttributeNode in HTML.

But for selenium, it can only find/return ElementNode, you can use display text of TextNode in XPath to match you wanted ElementNode, but can't ask selenium to return TextNode.

Therefore remove the `text()` at the ending of your xpath, then call `getText()` api of `WebElement` to get the text of element.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a *List* with the desired elements inducing *WebDriverWait* for the *visibility Of All Elements* and extract the required *text* in a loop and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://global.prana.com/women/clothing/tops.html#page=1");
  List<WebElement> allElements = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//h2[@class='product-name']")));
  for (WebElement element: allElements)
        System.out.println((element).getText());
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  FILLARY TOP
  REMI WAFFLE PULLOVER
  SHEA WAFFLE HOODIE
  SHELTON TOP
  PRAIRIE GROVE SWEATER
  PERCY TOP
  CHARLEY TOP
  ASTER TUNIC
  ASTER TUNIC PLUS
  FOUNDATION TURTLENECK
  FOUNDATION V-NECK PLUS
  FOUNDATION WRAP
  COZY UP T-SHIRT
  FOUNDATION WRAP PLUS
  FOUNDATION LONG SLEEVE CREW
  FOUNDATION LONG SLEEVE TUNIC
  SEABORD LONG SLEEVE TOP
  SEABORD SHORT SLEEVE TOP
  FOUNDATION SHORT SLEEVE V-NECK
  BACALL TOP
  PUREST TANK
  AZUL TOP
  SHILOH TOP
  ```